# Facebook Like Button not working in IE

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I am having trouble getting consistent behaviour from my Facebook Like button. I have created this example which I believe to be the simplest possible implementation...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fb:like href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have saved this as an HTML file which I am serving from a webserver running on my machine (localhost - I assume this won't be a problem as the page I'm 'liking' in this example is public-facing).

If I try this in Google Chrome, it appears to work without a problem.

When I try it in IE9, the like button renders, but when I click it, a new IE window opens which is mostly blank apart from a blue Facebook header.  The URL of this page is: http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com%2F

This is really confusing me as the example is about as simple as it gets! Any help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT:** A little more information. If I go to Facebook in IE9 and log-out, then try my like button again, a new window still opens but this time I can login. After logging in, though, I still get taken to the same blank page.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue - IE only. I'm accessing the full website links in the code. Did you ever find out what causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In desperation, I tried accessing my local page from http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost

This appears to have solved (or at least worked around) the problem.

I would *love* to hear from anyone who can explain what this is all about!!

Comment: your work around was perfect. finally found this post after 5 hours of research :)

Comment: +1 and more info needed.  I have the same problem, and changing to IP fixes it.  I suspect it's because we're testing from localhost..